# Read am3335x i/o mux output state?

Tags: io, state, cpu-registers, microprocessors, mux

On the TI am3335x processor, the physical i/o pins are muxed to different internal registers.

I can read the state of these internal registers, but what I would like to do is read the
state on the physical output of the mux instead, so that I can know the state of the connection to the outside world regardless of which mux channel is selected. Are there any registers for each mux output? I can't find any info on that. Is it even possible on the am3335x, or do I have to check the state of the internal registers for the mux-mode that is selected at the time, to know the state at the output of the mux?

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible. There are no registers that reflect the raw pin state.
Best Regards
Biser